# Xamarin android in-app purchases 0

Tags: android, xamarin, google-play, in-app-purchase

Somehow google keeps telling my users(my app) that the user has bought 0 items.
But they did!

This is wat returns 0:

```
_purchase = _serviceConnection.BillingHandler.GetPurchases(ItemType.Product);

Toast.MakeText(GetThis(), "You have bought " + _purchase.Count + " products", ToastLength.Long).Show();
```

_purchase is an `private IList<Purchase> _purchase;`

This is what my `OnCreate()` looks like:

```
// Create a new connection to the Google Play Service
_serviceConnection = new InAppBillingServiceConnection(this, "VERRY LONG STRING");
_serviceConnection.OnConnected += async () =>
{
    _products = await _serviceConnection.BillingHandler.QueryInventoryAsync(new List<string> {
        "all"
    }, ItemType.Product);

    // Were any products returned?
    if (_products == null)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(GetThis(), "Something wen't wrong", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        // No, abort
        return;
    }

    if (!payed)
    {
        // Not paid atleast not saved
        _purchase = _serviceConnection.BillingHandler.GetPurchases(ItemType.Product);

        Toast.MakeText(GetThis(), "You have bought " + _purchase.Count + " products", ToastLength.Long).Show();

        if (_purchase.Count == 0)
        {
            payed = true;

            ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = prefs.Edit();
            editor.PutBoolean("payed", payed);
            editor.Apply();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.MakeText(GetThis(), "thanks!", ToastLength.Long).Show();
    }

    BuildDefaultButtons();
};

// Attempt to connect to the service
_serviceConnection.Connect();
```

This is very annoying since my app is already in production. As i tested it myself with a promo code i noticed this big issue.

Comment: If there is an error getting the list of products, the BillingHandler's `OnGetProductsError` event will be raised with the Response Code of the error. The Response Code can be compared against the BillingResult static class to determine the reason for the failure.

Comment: @Fahadsk the product list itself is good also purching items works perfectly only getting the purchases doesn't work.

Comment: have you logged any error in `OnPurchaseConsumedError` callback ?

Comment: @Fahadsk It doesn't log anything